# Any software for drawing vectors with predefined effects?

Tags: graphs, vector-graphics

`PGF/TikZ` is a great language for drawing vectors. It has a practical library of shapes. For example, you can draw a 3D ball with one command only.

BUT `PGF/TikZ` is command-based. Even available GUIs are for testing commands (to be used in latex documents).

On the other hand, you need to make each and every effect in main vector programs like Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape. For example, you need to draw a circle, and add appropriate shadows to form a 3D ball (several steps instead one).

Is there any programs for drawing shapes with a predefined library.

I prefer linux, but Windows is OK too.